# AngularJs - Adding custom parameter to Request Header

Tags: angularjs, http, get, http-headers, cors

I'm having a bit of a problem trying to make a GET request.

This is what I'm trying:

---

```
var config = {headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ZGllZ28uY2FsYXphbnNAZ3J1cG9udC5jb20uYnI6MTIz',
         'grupont.auth.idescola':'409651',
         'grupont.auth.usercontext':'blahblah@blah.com.br'

     }
$http.get('http://localhost:8585/api/rest/contratosAdesao/cursosConsoleTO/29526757', config).success(function(){}).error(function(){});
```

---

I'm trying to get some basic information from the server. This is the Request Header:

---

```
Accept:*/
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, authorization, get,grupont.auth.idescola, grupont.auth.usercontext
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8585
Origin:127.0.0.1:43013
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:127.0.0.1:43013/cursos.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.93 Safari/537.36
```

I'm also getting this as a General Header:

```
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:401 Unauthorized
```

---

The `grupont.auth.idescola` and `grupont.auth.usercontext` get added to `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.

Does anyone knows what it it happening? I'm trying to make a CORS call to a server, and I need to send some parameters on the Request Header.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: try adding `withCredentials : true` header. Seems you control the remote service so debug there to see why authorization is denied

Comment: Hey, thanks for the message, but I got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone else has the same problem, the issue was with the server (jboss) response to the CORS request. It has to respond correctly to the preflight OPTIONS request.

If I send the GET Request with these parameters on the Header Request:

```
'withCredentials':true,
'Authorization': 'Basic ZGllZ28uY2FsYXphbnNAZ3J1cG9udC5jb20uYnI6MTIz',
'grupont.auth.idescola':'409651',
'grupont.auth.usercontext':'blahblah@blah.com.br'
```

The server needs to respond with:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:grupont.auth.idescola,grupont.auth.usercontext,withCredentials,authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Allow:GET, OPTIONS, HEAD
```

And then the process can continue.

Hope it helps someone.